# CSS Nth-Child 3n hierarchy structure

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

With how my HTML is structure I am having hard time selecting `3n` child. It doesn't seem even notice the `3n` selector of class `heroLetter`, but if I use the `1n` child selector the code notices the class, but it also selects every `div`. I am not sure how to call the `3n` child selector with this structure of classes I have made.

Code:

```css
.heroLetter {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 600px;
  color: #f5543a;
  position: relative;
}
.windowWrapper .section .heroLetter:nth-child(3n) {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200px;
  color: #f5543a;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="section1" class="windowWrapper">
    <div class="section group">
      <h1 class="introH1">
                <span class="Grand">GRAND</span>
                <span class="Stand">STAND</span>
             </h1>
      <p class="introP">A new font.</p>
      <a href="#section2" class="arrowDown removeText">scroll down</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="windowWrapper">
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_6_of_12">
        <h1>STORY</h1>
        <p>Grandstand invokes</p>
      </div>
      <div class="heroLetter">
        G
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="windowWrapper">
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_6_of_12">
        <h1>PROCESS</h1>
        <p>Grandstand invokes</p>
      </div>
      <div class="heroLetter">
        S
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section4" class="windowWrapper form">
    <div class="section group">
      <div class="col span_6_of_12">
        <h1>BEAM</h1>
        <p>Grandstand invokes</p>
      </div>
      <div class="heroLetter">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        a
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please indicate target with a comment within the HTML. ex.`<!--I want that one-->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nth-child` refers to children of the same parent only.

You could adjust your code to refer to the outer most common element.
Some css like this should help you:

```
.windowWrapper:nth-child(4n) .section .heroLetter {}
```

In this case it's the 4th `windowWrapper` since it contains your 3rd `heroLetter`